# justify-self "is not a known CSS property" in CSS4, but justify-contents doesn't work

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm using css grids in an MVC VS project.
I'm trying to "float right" a grid item.

I tried using:

```
.navbar-right
{
    grid-column: 3;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

This compiles fine, but doesn't have the desired effect.

I then tried:

```
.navbar-right
{
    grid-column: 3;
    justify-self: end;
}
```

This throws a warning "justify-self is not a known css 4 property" ...

Why does justify-self not exist and if I'm supposed to use `content` why does justify-content not work?!

Is `justify-self` supposed to be in-line only? Isn't that bad practice?

Comment: I would take a look at this: [Why there is no CSS4 - explaining CSS Levels](https://www.rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/09/13/why-there-is-no-css4-explaining-css-levels/)

Comment: Where do you get that warning? on the editor? it could be outdated it could be incomplete. Just respect what the documentation says, not editor warnings https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content. Also, note that `justify-content` justifies the content of an element, and `justify-self` justifies the element relative to it's parent, these are two different things.

Comment: Yeah it's in the Visual Studio 2017 community editor. I updated loads very recently so surprised if it's out of date but will look into it. And I thought I was understanding justify-content, the demos seem to be showing me it's what I want but only `justify-self: end` or good old `float: right` works for me... maybe I don't quite understand it yet!?